# What is the difference between yield and return?

Tags: python

I've read that `yield` is a generator but I can't really see what it implies since the output of the following function is exactly the same:

```
def yieldFunction(number):
    for x in range(number) :
        yield x*2

def returnFunction(number):
    output=[]
    for x in range(number) :
        output.append(x*2)
    return output

for x in yieldFunction(10):
    print(x)

print('-'*20)

for x in returnFunction(10):
    print(x)
```

Output:

> 0
>   2
>   4
>   6
>   8
>   10
>   12
>   14
>   16
>   18
>
> 0
>   2
>   4
>   6
>   8
>   10
>   12
>   14
>   16
>   18

In which case one is preferred over the other?

Comment: Go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do

Comment: with `yield` you use less memory - try to run second example with very big value and will use a lot of memory. And `yield` doesn't have to wait for full list which may need some time.

Comment: Thanks, very illustrative suggestion, just tried it and could see the result

Comment: using `while True:` in `yieldFunction` you can create endless generator - and you can still use it in loop or using `it = yieldFunction(), value = next(it)`. Using  `while True:` in `returnFunction` it will never end function `returnFunction` and program will hang.